# How to install the Vala environemt?

Tags: software-installation, compiler, vala

Is there a repository so that I can install Vala with `apt-get`, or do I have to download and install it manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended method is to add a [repository](https://launchpad.net/~vala-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to your system:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/vala-team/ppa/ubuntu utopic main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/vala-team/ppa/ubuntu utopic main
```

If you are unsure on how to add this [read the link on the launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/+help-soyuz/ppa-sources-list.html). Verification of the repository:

```
Signing key: 1024R/7DAAC99C ([What is this?][3]) 
Fingerprint: 008940D610E4CD892340AB0A4CE987B57DAAC99C
```

After this you can use Ubuntu Software Center or `sudo apt-get install valac-0.26` from command line to install the latest stable version of vala (read the description on the launchpad page for more details).

From our [community page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Vala) on vala:

> The Vala team PPA also contains:
>
> - libgee - Libgee is a collection library providing GObject-based interfaces and classes for commonly used data structures.
> - vtg - Vala Toys for gEdit is an experimental collection of plugins that extends the gEdit editor to make it a better programmer editor
>     for the Vala language.
> - valide - Val(a)IDE is an Integrated Development Environment (IDE) for the Vala programming language.
> - gtksourcecompletion - used by the editor packages. Source completion is not working in the PPA builds; there is no library file created.

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:vala-team/ppa `