# How to install Vala on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: 16.10, vala

How to install Vala on Ubuntu 16.10?

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612342/how-to-install-the-vala-environemt) doesn't work. It says:

```
E: Package 'valac-0.26' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 4):

[vala page on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~vala-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) specify that you should:

PPA description

Vala packages and some related libraries which are actively maintained for Precise/12.04 and newer!

vala 0.34.x is the suggested series to use

Adding the PPA and its key is as simple as:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vala-team
```

Afterwards please run:

```
sudo apt update
```

install valac

```
sudo apt install valac
```

vala-doc:

```
sudo apt install vala-0.36-doc
```

valac-dbg:

```
sudo apt install valac-dbg
```

[More info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Vala)